# Can't add any ppa in Ubuntu 17.04 with gpg keyserver failed: end of file

Tags: 17.04, ppa, gnupg

After Updating Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04, I cannot add any PPA. For e.g. adding this ppa I get the following error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa

Backports of the latest TeX Live from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
More info: https://launchpad.net/~texlive-
backports/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp702ddoyv/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: End of file
Failed to add key.
```

I am behind a proxy server. I tried to add proxy in dirmngr.conf under ~/.gnupg directory as follows:

```
#honor-http-proxy
http-proxy <PROXY>
```

It seems like dirmngr.conf is not getting honoring http proxy.

I can manually add a key with apt-key command when I give provide keyserver options with http-proxy=value.

Everything used to work fine in 16.04. Can someone please shed some light on why this could be happening?